# How to set value as undefined in 'this.state' inside constructor?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to have an object, `CreditData`, which is undefined when I start the application. First when I submit the form, should it set the data (it is going to call an API which returns the data).

However, according to my Typescript, I am forced to set all values in the `this.state` inside the constructor.

If I do something as below where I do this: `this.state = { loading: false, query: '', creditData: null };` , I get the "`Type 'null' is not assignable to type CreditData'` (and same error with undefined).

How do I wait assigning the `creditData` value until after the submit?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

interface CompanySearchState {
    loading: boolean;
    query: string;
    creditData: CreditData
}

export class CompanySearch extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, CompanySearchState> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { loading: false, query: '', creditData: null };
    }

    public render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Search company</h1>

            <div className='form-group'>
                <input type='text' className='form-control' value={this.state.query} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>

            <button onClick={() => { this.searchVat() } }>Search</button>
        </div>;
    }

    handleChange(evt:any) {
        this.setState({ query: evt.target.value });
    }

    searchVat() {
        alert('abe');
    }

}

interface CreditData {
    Description: string;
    Rating: number;
}
```

Comment: just dont add it to the state until you need it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, `null` and `undefined` can't be assigned to types which are not written to accept them. So you have two solutions:

```
// 1. My personal recommendation, define an initial value for creditData
this.state = {
  loading: false,
  query: '',
  creditData: { description: '', rating: 0 }
}

// 2. Make creditData optional in your interface (and initialize with undefined instead of null)
// This is useful if you want to differentiate states
// between whether or not you have the data, or if there is no useful default value.
interface CompanySearchState {
    loading: boolean;
    query: string;
    creditData?: CreditData
}
```